# JQuery dropdown menu not working on a wordpress WooCommerce shop page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu for my Wordpress shop (WooCommerce) - https://shop.sin.org.pl/sklep/ .

The problem is, while the dropdown menu does show up, the  image it should return does not. Does anyone know how to force show it right next to the dropdown?

Code: https://pastebin.com/2ZcyKAh8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Testy</title>
<style type="text/css">
   .box{
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js">            </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
        if(optionValue){
            $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
            $("." + optionValue).show();
        } else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Wybierz substancje</option>
        <option value="1">LSD</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="1 box">
    <a href="http://sin.org.pl" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://s14.postimg.org/s15q8k3u9/Untitled-1.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's so many jQuery errors on that page, that I wouldn't know where to begin. Do you use Firebug or the debug/dom tools built into the browser?

Comment: Wordpress and Woocommerce... The code I actually can edit is just what I pasted here.

Comment: The code works, should be optimized but works... Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: You should be using jQuery() not $() in WordPress

Comment: The code does work itself, but what should show up on selection from the dropdown menu does not appear on the website. Most likely WooCommerce is overwriting it, but perhaps there is a way to bypass it... Thank you for your time and help folks :)

Comment: @PhillHealey omg that was it!

Comment: @user3158006 Please accept my answer as the correct answer & maybe upvote some of my comments then. Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `jQuery()` not `$()` in WordPress

This may also relate to the huge number of error showing up in Firebug for that page.

Comment: Genius. Kudos! That simple fix was quick and saved me plenty of time.

Comment: @user3158006 You really should use some form of Dev tool. Firebug is generally considered the best. Some of your jQuery isn't loading due to it being loaded over http and not https. You should add a htaccess rule to force everything over https.